# path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'), AttributeError: module 'polls.views' has no attribute 'IndexView'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-generic-views

how to solve this :
i am using generic views method in django and facing this error while creating my first poll app ...

```
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'), AttributeError: module 'polls.views' has no attribute 'IndexView'
```

my urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juHoF.png)

Comment: It seems like you do not have `IndexView` in views.py file. Can you show us the views.py file?

Comment: Share your `views.py`. Please do *not* name your view `DetailView`.

Comment: class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

Comment: i have added the image of view.py in question

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, i am new to stack overflow..